# Implementing Role-Based Permissions in an Ionic Application

Tags: ionic-framework, module, permissions, file-permissions, roles

when a user login its all permissions are returned as a response now a page that have multiple permissions user will show those parts of pages only he has granted same for all pages i used a technique like in view *ngIf="haspermit (role, permisson , moduleName)" but this is not appropriate process that why i want to use particular flag...i work on permission mangement first time so i am unable to understand whole process . can any one who work on same can guide?

```
  "result": [
        [
            {
                "roleName": "hello",
                "moduleName": "ok,m.",
                "permissions": [
                    {
                        "permissionName": "mmn",
                        "hasPermission": true
                    },
                    {
                        "permissionName": "lp",
                        "hasPermission": false
                    },
                    {
                        "permissionName": "ou",
                        "hasPermission": false
                    },
                    {
                        "permissionName": "lp",
                        "hasPermission": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "roleName": "hello",
                "moduleName": "lll",
                "permissions": [
                    {
                        "permissionName": "mmn",
                        "hasPermission": true
                    },
                    {
                        "permissionName": "lp",
                        "hasPermission": false
                    },
                    {
                        "permissionName": "ou",
                        "hasPermission": false
                    },
                    {
                        "permissionName": "lp",
                        "hasPermission": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "roleName": "stg",
                "moduleName": "ok,m.",
                "permissions": [
                    {
                        "permissionName": "mmn",
                        "hasPermission": true
                    },
                    {
                        "permissionName": "lp",
                        "hasPermission": false
                    },
                    {
                        "permissionName": "ou",
                        "hasPermission": false
                    },
                    {
                        "permissionName": "lp",
                        "hasPermission": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "roleName": "stg",
                "moduleName": "lll",
                "permissions": [
                    {
                        "permissionName": "mmn",
                        "hasPermission": true
                    },
                    {
                        "permissionName": "lp",
                        "hasPermission": false
                    },
                    {
                        "permissionName": "ou",
                        "hasPermission": false
                    },
                    {
                        "permissionName": "lp",
                        "hasPermission": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```